# Custom models not included in Stalker worker

Tags: beanstalkd

I'm trying to get Stalker working with Beanstalkd in my Ramaze application. I can enqueue jobs no problem, but my worker doesn't recognize my custom models. Here is my jobs.rb:

require 'stalker'
include Stalker
BEANSTALK_URL = '0.0.0.0:11300'
job 'award_badges' do |args|
    Badge.award_badges(args[:user_id], args[:badge_category])
end

I run the jobs.rb with stalker jobs.rb and always receive the error: Exception NameError -> uninitialized constant Badge

In all the stalker examples no libraries are included, how does Stalker know about those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not loading your enviroment with your jobs, here is a well formatted **jobs.rb**:

```
require File.expand_path("../environment", __FILE__)

require 'stalker'
include Stalker

job "my_job" do |args|
# Do something here...
end
```

As you can see in the first three lines we first require our rails enviroment and then stalker, so it can be aware about your models and stuff.

Cheers!